# Bootstrap 4 - Assign placeholder to <select> form input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I've searched a bit but the found solutions here on SO seems not working for me. I have a select input field and I want to assign it a placeholder. I'm using bootstrap 4 and to manage the front-end.
As I understand from the documentation I need to assign the selected hidden or selected disabled to the `<option>` tag I want to use as placeholder. I've tried but didn't worked.I don't know if this is because I'm using vue.js, is there a fix?

```
        <label>Filter List</label>
        <select
          class="form-control"
          v-model="listFilter"
          v-on:change="filterList()"
        >
          <option value="" selected disabled class="text-hide">Select filter</option>
          <option value="a">All</option>
          <option value="f">Fe</option>
          <option value="m">Mas</option>
          <option value="s">Tru</option>
          <option value="c">Cou</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/zjvLpg9w/ but on jsfiddle the issue will not happen, maybe because they are using bootstrap 5 alpha or maybe because the select isn't loaded in a vue component?